# How can I obtain this division's limit without using derivatives?

Tags: analysis, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{y}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(1+y)\right)}$$
Can anybody help me? I can use basic properties of limits, and some of those basic known limits. I know it would be easier with derivatives, but I was just wondering if it's possible without  L-Hospital's rule, derivatives, Taylor series.

Thank you in advance!

My ideas for now:
changing cosine into sine.
Maybe that. I have no other clue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(1+y)\right)} = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)} = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y}{-\sin\left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)} \\
= -\frac{2}{\pi}\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)} = -\frac{2}{\pi}(1) = -\frac{2}{\pi}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: How come we are assuming 0 / 0 is 1, or even that the limit approaches 1. . ?

Comment: @Lemony: We aren't: we're using one of the "basic known limits" involving $\sin$.

Comment: @Hukyl: absolutely right.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot But how would you derive that limit without Taylor series, derivatives or L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @fibonatic: You can cheat and use the small angle approximation... but I'm not sure that's terribly rigorous.

Comment: @fibonatic: The question was how to solve the problem with the basic limits, not how to prove the basic limits. (and, IIRC, the usual pedagogy in introductory courses is that the derivatives of the trig functions are proven using the basic limits anyways, rather than the other way around)

Comment: @user246608: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$ is derived geometrically in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151).

Answer (score 16):

HINT:

$$\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2+A\right)=-\sin A$$

and $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h=\text{ ?}$$